# Numba: Parallelization not working properly

Tags: python, numba

I have written some code in Python and wanted to improve it using Numba's function decorators. Using a just-in-time compiler works fine (`@jit`). However, when I tried to parralize my code, speeding it up even more, the programm strangely runs slower than the non-parralized version.

Here is my code:

```
@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def get_output(input, depth, input_size, kernel_size, input_depth, kernels, bias):
    output = np.zeros((depth, input_size[0] - kernel_size + 1, input_size[0] - kernel_size + 1))
    for k in numba.prange(depth):
        for i in numba.prange(input_depth):
            output[k] += valid_correlate(input[i], kernels[k][i])
        output[k] += bias[k]
    return output

@numba.njit(fastmath=True)
def apply_filter(mat, filter, point):
    result = 0
    end_point = (min(mat.shape[0], point[0] + filter.shape[0]), 
                 min(mat.shape[1], point[1] + filter.shape[1]))
    point = (max(0, point[0]), max(0, point[1]))
    area = mat[point[0]:end_point[0], point[1]:end_point[1]]
    if filter.shape != area.shape:
        s_filter = filter[0:area.shape[0], 0:area.shape[1]]
    else:
        s_filter = filter
    i_result = np.multiply(area, s_filter)
    result = np.sum(i_result)
    return result

@numba.njit(nogil=True)
def valid_correlate(mat, filter):
    f_mat = np.zeros((mat.shape[0] - filter.shape[0] + 1, mat.shape[1] - filter.shape[0] + 1))

    for x in range(f_mat.shape[0]):
        for y in range(f_mat.shape[1]):
            f_mat[x, y] = apply_filter(mat, filter, (x, y))
    return f_mat
```

With `parralel=True` it takes about **0.07** seconds, whilst its about **0.056** seconds without it.
I can't seem to figure out the problem here and would be glad for any help!
Regards
-Eirik

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using numba with np.concatenate is not efficient in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70339388/using-numba-with-np-concatenate-is-not-efficient-in-parallel)

Comment: Not really, after reading trough the post, I still don't know what I should change in my code.

Comment: Well the post say that the problem due to a "*contention of the allocator*" itself due to "*many implicit small temporary arrays*". Thus, you should avoid creating temporary array. Which mean calling less Numpy functions on arrays or to use the `out` parameter when possible. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70475773/numba-parallel-code-slower-than-its-sequential-counterpart/70477409#70477409) is another similar post (amongst few other ones). This is a recurrent issue with Numba (but in fact the real problem is Numpy though the allocation function is slow).

Comment: I replaced the numpy functions of `apply_filter()` which fastened the code. However it's still not faster than the sequential version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, creating temporary Numpy array is expensive because **allocations do not scale** in parallel but also because **memory-bound core also do not scale**. Here is a modified (untested) code:

```py
@numba.njit(fastmath=True)
def apply_filter(mat, filter, point):
    result = 0
    end_point = (min(mat.shape[0], point[0] + filter.shape[0]), 
                 min(mat.shape[1], point[1] + filter.shape[1]))
    point = (max(0, point[0]), max(0, point[1]))
    area = mat[point[0]:end_point[0], point[1]:end_point[1]]
    if filter.shape != area.shape:
        s_filter = filter[0:area.shape[0], 0:area.shape[1]]
    else:
        s_filter = filter
    res = 0.0
    # Replace the slow `np.multiply` call creating a temporary array
    for i in range(area.shape[0]):
        for j in range(area.shape[1]):
            res += area[i, j] + s_filter[i, j]
    return res
```

I assumed the shape of `area` and `s_filter` are the same. If this is not the case, then please provide a complete reproducible example.

Also note that the first call is slow because of **compilation time**. One ways to fix that is to provide the function signature. See the [Numba documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jit.html#eager-compilation) for more information about this.

By the way, the operation looks like a custom convolution. If so, then note that FFTs are known to speed this up a lot if the filter is relatively big. For small filter the code can be faster if the compiler know the size of the array at compile time. If the filter is relatively big and [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_kernel), then the whole computation can be split in much faster steps.

Comment: How do I tell the compiler the size of the array at compile time?

Comment: One solution is to put an assert which is also great because it is safe. something like `assert array.shape == (3, 3)`. The compiler will take benefit from this hypothesis. That being said, the hypothesis tends not to be propagated across parallel loops yet. The alternative manual solution is simply to replace a variable range-based loop by a constant like `for i in range(3): ...`. The compiler will unroll the loop so to make this faster.

Comment: The array's size can vary depending on which class instance is calling the function, so I can't use constants like 3. Do you know how do deal with this?

Comment: Indeed, in this case you cannot use a constant. The usual solution in native programs is to compile multiple function variants with different compile-time values and use the right function at runtime. However, this is only OK in Numba if the number of cases is small (eg. few values) because of the overhead of the JIT. In C/C++, the compilation time is often not a problem. If the number of cases is big, then the best solution is simply to keep the run-time value (ie. as in the answer).